# Magento 2: How to call CMS Block in email templates?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, cms-block

In Magento 1, we can call CMS Block in email templates like that:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="mail_include_header"}}
```

I try above code for Magento 2, but it does not work.

How can we call CMS Block in email templates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can try:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" area='frontend' block_id="mail_include_header"}}
```

We can see more how to add a block to email: `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/shipment_new.html`

Comment: I have two cms block with same identifier for store specific. Is above way will pick store specific block Or we need to pass store-id ?

Comment: @Atul its store view specific.