# Is using {{block}} to include a CMS block in an Email the right way - or how to include a block in strict email template mode?

Tags: magento2.3.3

We are running into problems with the I-ways PayPal Module with email templates that use

```
<div>{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" area="frontend" block_id="agb_email_german"}}</div>
```

(see also [Magento 2: How to call CMS Block in email templates?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136357/magento-2-how-to-call-cms-block-in-email-templates))

In Magento 2.3.

I was wondering if that is the right way to include a static block or if there is a better way, especially because of the [upcoming strict mode changes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email-migration.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally always advocate to use Block classes in email templates, exactly for the purpose you are describing: Having a CMS Block, so that the merchant is able to manage content from within the Magento Admin Panel, without needing to override the email template itself.

In the DevDoc mentioned, I'm not seeing the impact of the strict mode on this block syntax ...

Comment: Turns out the problem was only with this module. Another PayPal Plus module works fine.